# Magento customers with no country or city

Tags: magento

I have a Magento Store. I have exported customers list from customer tab - few of the customers have country or city = NULL or empty.

How this can be possible? Country and city is mandatory fields aren't they?

Any one had the same issue please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The country and city fields (and others) are not customer attributes. They are address attributes.
A customer can have an account but no addresses.
Hence you get the customers with no city or country.
To reproduce the (so called) issue create an account then look for that account in the backend grid. You will see there is no city or country for that either.